# Why does Thymeleaf (sometimes?) call an isX() method for a non-boolean field?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have this code in my view

```html
<form th:action="@{/save-user}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
<!-- some other forms -->
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{enabled}" />
```

`enabled` is a field of the type `byte` that stores either zero or one (it's necessary for Spring Security purposes)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
// ...
    @Column
    private byte enabled;
// ...
    public byte getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    } // I have a getter for the field
```

The `User` class also has this method

```java
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled == 1;
    }
```

As you see, it returns a `boolean`

I noticed that when I use this expression `th:field="*{enabled}"`, Thymeleaf for some reason calls that `boolean` method instead of calling a getter for the `enabled` field

[Thymeleaf expressing his intention to call the boolean method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BFXg.png)

It causes an error

```
ERROR 5880 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "user-update-info" - line 53, col 34)] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source to convert from must be an instance of [@javax.persistence.Column byte]; instead it was a [java.lang.Boolean]
```

I know I can call the getter explicitly (in my opinion, it makes the code a bit uglier)

[Explicitly calling the getter for enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2IM5.png)

but why does Thymeleaf behave this way?

Comment: Hi & Welcome! It's already super ugly to have duplicate/ambiguous "property" in one "java bean"/pojo ...and as long you cannot overcome this: who cares about esthetic?;)

Comment: @xerx593 What do you mean?

Comment: Pragmatic/quick workaround: `@Column(name="enabled")
    private byte someCustomName;//e.g. "my enabled" or "enabledByte"...` (since `boolean isEnabled()` is prescribed by interface, we can/should name our "internal field" custom ...to extinguish ambiguousness...)

Comment: "pro solution": don't "expose" your "entities" *at all*! ...but use a (n unambiguous/several(uc-dependant...e.g. to implement interfaces)) "dto layer"(s)..

Comment: @xerx593 I didn't get the last part. And I still don't understand why Thymeleaf preferred that boolean method to the getter

Comment: you have to excuse tyhmeleaf (I do)...which "`enabled`" should it choose? (throw exception(?), boolean/byte, get/is, "first"/"last", "random"?)

Comment: @xerx593 there is a system to it, right? Thymeleaf didn't just randomly pick a method, did it?

Comment: #last part: use `User` only (in repository and) "up to (inside) your `@Service` layer"! Beyond that expose only (new class(es)) `UserDto`, `UserFooDto` and `UserBarDto` ( "foo" and "bar" according to what you do with them .. eg "Edit" ..or "Full" or "Short"..."Request", "Response",...) ...of course you have to pay for this "de-coupling" with a "mapping" (inside your services -> [tag:mapstruct]), then `@Controller`(+thymeleaf) work only with `UserXXXDto`s ..and dosen't know anything about `User`

Comment: and #pragmatic approach: remove ambiguity by renaming `byte enabled` (+get/set(, preserving the (sql) column name))

Comment: #there is a system to it, right?: sure there is! (for me) somewhere hidden between "spring model population" and "thymeleaf engine" (it's all open source)...but finding/"fixing" it is like (Matthew 7.3) "And why beholdest thou the mote that is in thy brother's eye, but considerest not the beam that is in thine own eye?"